# Flutter App localization : How to get value with String key?

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart, localization

I can get value of translations with methods like that :

```
AppLocalizations.of(context).closed
```

if I have "closed" as String variable like that :

```
String c = "closed";
```

how can I get the value with c Variable :

```
AppLocalizations.of(context).c  ( This Makes Error "The getter 'c' isn't defined for the type 'AppLocalizations'")
```

Comment: I followed the documentation here:
https://localizely.com/i18n-questions/flutter/how-to-get-a-localization-message-with-a-dynamic-string-key-value-in-flutter/

Answer (score 2):

I followed the Flutter official doc for Internationalization, but I haved the same problem. So, I have installed on my ide (Visual Studio Code) the plugin Flutter Intl (localizely.flutter-intl), it's available also in Android Studio.
To get the dynamic tranlsations, I haved use the ICU format type called: Select (https://support.crowdin.com/icu-message-syntax/#select).
For example:

main.dart

```
localizationsDelegates: [
  S.delegate,
  GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
  GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,
  GlobalCupertinoLocalizations.delegate,
],
supportedLocales: S.delegate.supportedLocales,
```

init_it.arb

```
"gender": "{gender, select, male{Maschio} female{Femmina} other{entrambi}}",
  "@gender": {
    "description": "Gender type",
    "placeholders": {
      "gender": {}
    }
  }
```

myWidget.dart

```
Text(
     S.of(context).gender(gender.name)
   )
```